# Checking for nil?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to check for nil but always get the following error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

**Code**

```
require 'csv'
require 'addressable/uri'

lines = CSV.readlines("test.csv")

a = lines.map{|s| {timestamp: s[0], url: s[1], ip: s[2]} }

a.each do |data|
  if Addressable::URI.parse(data[:url]).query_values["v"].nil?
    puts "nil"
  else
    puts "not nil"
  end
end
```

From Joe's example, this seems to have worked for me:

```
# test if each element exists
if data[:uri] = Addressable::URI.parse(data[:url]).query_values
  # test if the value "v" exists
  if Addressable::URI.parse(data[:url]).query_values["v"].nil?
    puts "nil"
  else
    # the value "v" exists, so parse it out
    puts "not nil"
    v = Addressable::URI.parse(data[:url]).query_values["v"]
    puts v
  end
else
  puts "no query values"
end
```

I have added comments to supplement my understanding.

Thanks.

Comment: Can u tell the value of "data"

Comment: +1 for downvote with no reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test that each element exists before using `[]`

```
 if data and data[:uri] and Addressable::URI.parse(data[:url]).query_values 
         and not Addressable::URI.parse(data[:url]).query_values["v"].nil?
    puts "not nil"
 else
    puts "nil"
 end
```

possibly assign an intermediate variable to avoid parsing twice

```
if data and data[:uri] and qv=Addressable::URI.parse(data[:url]).query_values 
   if qv["v"].nil?
      puts "nil"
   else
      puts "not nil"
   end
else 
   puts "no query values"
end
```

Comment: `and` and `or` [may not behave](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/) the way you think they do.

Comment: @Jeffrey yes, the `and` and `&&` operators have different precedence.  Notice that the link you posted says "and is useful for chaining related operations together until one of them returns nil or false" which is exactly what I am doing here.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that either `data` or `Addressable::URI.parse(data[:url]).query_values` is `nil`, so you don't make it to the `nil?`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to take a look at [`#fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) which raises an error if the key does not exist. Using `[]` may return `nil` and that `nil` will cause an error somewhere else where you wouldn't expect it, making it hard to debug.

In your case it might be `data[:url]` or `query_values` that is returning `nil`.